# How can i change text using post requests? (ANGULAR)

Tags: javascript, angular, http, http-post

I want to be able of sending a post request to my Angular application and when the app receives the request it changes the text to a value specified.

I really want to know how to do this. And even if it's actually doable using just angular and js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending a request to the application in the browser of a user is not possible. But you could send a request **from** the application in the browser to a backend or web-server and send the text as response to the request, see the [official angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/http) about how to do that with the `HttpClient` module.

Comment: Thanks, i'll check them out!

Answer (score 0):

Webapp can't respond to an HTTP Request.
but WebSocket could satisfy your proposal.